# Django: how to read a property of a model through a function?

Tags: django

I have my function like this:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(EditView, self).get_initial()
    u = self.request.user
    initial['user_last_name'] = u.last_name if u.last_name else u''
    initial['email'] = u.email if u.email else u''
    return initial
```

I will have a lot of fields to pre-fill so I'd like to do something like this (the following code *doesnt work*):

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(EditView, self).get_initial()

    def apply_initial(idx, obj, prop):
        initial[idx] = obj[prop] if getattr(obj, prop) else u''

    u = self.request.user
    apply_initial('user_first_name', u, 'first_name')
    apply_initial('user_last_name', u, 'last_name')
    # ... and so on
```

I get:

```
'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What am I missing to make it work?

Comment: Shouldn't `obj[prop]` be `getattr(obj, prop)`? BTW, I don't see how your approach is better than the first approach.

Comment: I will have a lot of things to do, and one of the lines will be `initial['date_naissance'] = p.date_naissance if p.date_naissance else u''` whereas it could be shorter (= only twice the name of the property instead of three times) `apply_initial('date_naissance', u, 'date_naissance')`

Comment: You're right **`(°_°)"`** it was that simple: `obj[prop]` changed to `getattr(obj, prop)`. 18 hours work ain't good for debugging...  may I ask you to answer so I check your answer as valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access the prop as index of object. That should be `getattr(obj, prop)` instead of `obj[prop]`:

```
def apply_initial(idx, obj, prop):
    initial[idx] = getattr(obj, prop, u'')
```

Comment: You don't need either here. `getattr` takes a default: `getattr(obj, prop, '')`.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code you look if `u.last_name` has an empty value, not whether it exists. A shorter version of that code would be:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(EditView, self).get_initial()
    u = self.request.user
    initial['user_last_name'] = u.last_name or u''
    initial['email'] = u.email or u''
    return initial
```

The `or` operator in Python does not just return a boolean, but instead returns the left-hand value if it is non-empty, and otherwise returns the right-hand value.